# Component fails to auto import types from index.d.ts file in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a component called ColorBox, and inside of its folder I have the component itself, style of it and an index file and the `index.d.ts` file for my types:

```
  ColorBox
   |- Colorbox.tsx
   |- index.ts
   |- styles.ts
   |- index.d.ts
```

Here is my `index.d.ts` file:

```
export interface IProps {
  colorName: string;
  colorHex: string;
}

export interface IBGColor {
  backgroundColor: string;
}
```

and this is my `ColorBox.tsx` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

const ColorBox: React.FC<IProps> = ({ colorName, colorHex }) => {
  const boxColor: IBGColor = {
    backgroundColor: colorHex,
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.box, boxColor]}>
      <Text style={styles.boxText}>{colorName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ColorBox;
```

The problem is that the `IProps` and `IBGColor` types does not auto imported from `index.d.ts` file, how does it works, I've been reading articles about TypeScript and it was mentioned that if you put an `index.d.ts` file inside of of the module, TypeScript will rely on that and try to find types from that file, but why it does not work in my component?

Should I explicitly import used types inside of my module? If so, then what is the benefit that `index.d.ts` file provides to us?

Also I use regular react-native init project, not any other fancy boilerplates!

Answer (score 0):

`index.d.ts` is used to declare global types, and as this types are available in  your whole project, you don't need to import it in your component,or export it in the `index.d.ts` file, just use it.

Comment: but it does not works, when i try to use it inside of my component, VsCode puts some red line underneath it and says `Cannot find name 'IProps'.ts(2304)`